# How to read data from text file and split in other textboxes?

Tags: vb.net

I can read all text from a text file(*.txt) using `readalltext` function in VB, but I want to split the text in other textboxes and one text file contains data and I want to split it, my text file is next:

```
x=first name
y=last name
z=age
```

And I want the code which can manage read data from that text file and after that split data in three textboxes like that.

```
textbox1.text=x
textbox2.text=y
textbox3.text=z
```

and last output was that

```
textbox1.text=first name
textbox2.text=last name
textbox3.text=age
```

So my problem is next: I want the code that can read x, y and z values from one text file.

Comment: The problem is not clear, maybe it'll help to see your code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I edited my question.

Comment: 1) What happens if you have more lines than textboxes? Or more textboxes than lines? 2) Are you writing the key and the value of each pair into the same textbox?

Comment: The aforementioned comment meant seeing actually working code (something which might be compiled and run in Visual Studio). By the way, you don't need to write the name of the language in the title,  just to add the right tag (also Visual Basic is usually understood as old VB6, before VB.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of code :

```
For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(file)
    Select Case True
        Case line.StartsWith("x=")
            TextBox1.Text = line.Split("=")(1)
        Case line.StartsWith("y=")
            TextBox2.Text = line.Split("=")(1)
        Case line.StartsWith("z=")
            TextBox3.Text = line.Split("=")(1)
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: as it's possible that "x", "y" or "z" might occur after the "=" sign, it would be better if the `Case` statements were of the form `Case line.StartsWith("x=")` and so on.

Comment: @Blackwood You're right ! I didn't think about it... But I think the OP will never see the edit...

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. The OP may not see it, but others might.

Answer (score 1):

Consider loading the contents into a `List(Of String())`:

```
Dim lst = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt").Select(Function(line) line.Split("=")).ToList
```

Then if you store your textboxes in a `List(Of TextBox)`, you could fill the corresponding textboxes appropriately:

```
For i = 0 To lst.Count
    textboxes(i).Text = lst(i)(1)
Next
```

Comment: A bit too advanced for him I think. But I like the way you arrange everything to fit everything on one line !

Comment: @Drarig29 It's basic LINQ; it's not advanced at all.

Comment: I think it's just a bit harder to understand for a beginner.